# Not being able to copy one drop down option to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to copy the values(options) of one dropdown list to another. Each time when the user click add button, I am appending new table row with several text boxes and a dropbox which is a copy of the original. Bellow is my code:

```
$(function(){
$("#addBtn").click(function(){
    var rows = $("#nofRowHidden").val();//get the current no of row
    rows++;
    $("#crsTable").append(
    '<tr>'+
    '<td><input type="text" name="assesmntNameTxtBx'+rows+'"/></td>'+
    '<td><input type="text" name="markRcvdTxtBx'+rows+'"/></td>'+
    '<td><input type="text" name="totalTxtBox'+rows+'"/></td>'+
    '<td>'+
    '<select name="drpDwnCrs'+rows+'">'+
    '</select>'+
    '</td>'+
    '</tr>'
    );
    //#drpDwnCrs1 was original drbdwn and populated with data from the database
    $("#drpDwnCrs1 option").clone().appendTo("#drpDwnCrs"+rows);

    $("#nofRowHidden").val(rows);//add current no of row to hidden txt bx
    });
 });
```

Above code correctly produce new row with textboxes. However, fails to copy the dropdown list's values.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `.appendTo("#drpDwnCrs"+rows)`, where `#` is the `id` selector.

When you create the `<select>`, you are using `'<select name="drpDwnCrs'+rows+'">'+`. That shows you set its `name` attribute...and not an `id` attribute. So that means your jQuery selector for the `appendTo` call won't find any element(s) and won't do anything.

Try changing that code I mentioned to:

```
.appendTo('select[name="drpDwnCrs' + rows + '"]')
```

Comment: thanks for pointing out the id mistake. I tried above mentioned method, but didn't work. So I created id for the dropdwn and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

May be this (/jsfiddle.net/slash197/a98U8/5/) is useful for you.

Comment: Thanks for your help appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

It will be

```
    // $("#drpDwnCrs1 option").clone().appendTo("#drpDwnCrs"+rows);  change this to

$("#drpDwnCrs"+rows).html($('#drpDwnCrs1').html());
```

This will copy the entire options of your original div to new div.

Comment: Thanks Debopam, the problem was my dumb mistake that, like Ian said, I didn't had id with that name. Appreciate your help.